# org.apache.jasper.JasperException in struts spring application

Tags: spring, hibernate, struts2

In my application(using struts,spring and hibernate) after successfully starting my tomcat when i tries to run it , i am getting error like

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /index.jsp(4,2) Attribute debug invalid for tag head according to TLD
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:40)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:407)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:236)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator$ValidateVisitor.checkXmlAttributes(Validator.java:1235)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator$ValidateVisitor.visit(Validator.java:846)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$CustomTag.accept(Node.java:1530)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2361)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2411)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visit(Node.java:2417)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Root.accept(Node.java:495)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2361)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator.validateExDirectives(Validator.java:1763)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:198)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:354)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:334)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:321)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:592)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:328)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:428)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:291)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:877)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:594)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:1675)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

JSP(Four line of code)

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<html>
    <head>
        <s:head theme="ajax" debug="true"/>
        <script type="text/javascript">
```

Comment: show the JSP/index.jsp and are you using ajax theme?

Comment: Yes i am using ajax theme. Please see edited question

Answer (score 2):

Well its because the Ajax theme is being handled using DOJO and you need to include this in your JSP.
First step is to add the Struts-dojo tags library in your jsp by adding following lines

```
<%@ taglib prefix="sx" uri="/struts-dojo-tags"%>
```

nest step is to enable the Ajax support by asking S2 to load required files and other things for Ajax theme to work properly.add following line sin your index.jsp

```
<sx:head />
```

Additional if you are using S2 version 2.1 and higher i will not recommend to use DOJO tags as the plugin has been deprecated, instead use simple DOJO/Jquery or there is already a Jquery plugin for S2

Comment: Still i am getting some other i think this is because of jar conflict.List of struts jar ---struts2-core-2.3.1.2.jar , struts2-dojo-plugin-2.1.6.jar (newly included)  , struts2-tiles-plugin-2.1.6.jar

Comment: If i am not adding struts2-tiles-plugin-2.1.6.jar then getting /index.jsp(2,46) File "/struts-dojo-tags" not found error

Comment: @chetan: i still suggest you not to go with dojo plugin,and i don't see any relation with tiles and DOJO.make sure the dojo plugin is in your class path. for more details refer this doc http://struts.apache.org/2.3.1/docs/ajax-tags.html